# Maxima simplifies 4*2^x to 2^(x+2) can I disable this simplification?

Tags: maxima

Maxima simplifies `4*2^x` to `2^(x+2)` can I somehow disable this simplification?

Comment: Why do you need it disabled? mathematically, you should get the same answer.

Comment: I use maxima to generate a solution in latex of a randomly generated questions. In one step of the solution, this simplification needs to be disabled.

Comment: You can set `simp:false` for this equation only.